# How can I compile my ColdFusion code for sourceless distribution, and have it be unreadable?

Tags: coldfusion

I've been tasked with creating a deployable version of a ColdFusion web app to be installed on a clients server. I'm trying to find a way to give them a compiled version of our code, and my first inclination was to use the CFCompile utility [that I found here](https://www.3gpp2.org/cfdocs/htmldocs/Admin/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbf364104-7fd0.html). However, after running CFCompile, most of the code in the CFM files is still readable. The only thing that appears to be obfuscated at all is the actual ColdFusion code - all of the SQL Queries are still perfectly readable. (Example in the screenshot below)

[image: A SQL Query stands out in a sea of gibberish]

The HTML and JavaScript are also still readable in the compiled code, but that doesn't matter as those can be seen in a web browser anyways.

Is there another way to distribute my source code in a format that is completely unreadable to the user? I'm guessing that for whatever method I choose, there will be some way of decompiling the code. That's not an issue, I just need to find a way to make it more difficult than opening the file and seeing the queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hostek has a pretty good write up on the subject over on their site - [How to Encrypt or Compile ColdFusion Files](https://wiki.hostek.com/How_to_Encrypt_or_Compile_ColdFusion_Files).

Basically, from that article:

> Using cfcompile.bat
> The cfcompile.bat utility will compile all .cfm and .cfc files within a given directory into Java bytecode. This has the effect of making your source code unreadable, and it also prevents ColdFusion from having to compile your ColdFusion files on first use which provides a small performance enhancement.

More details about using cfcompile.bat can be found in [ColdFusion's Documentation](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/Deploying+ColdFusion+Applications#DeployingColdFusionApplications-Usingthecfcompileutility)

> Using cfencode.exe
> The cfencode.exe utility will apply basic encryption to a specific file or directory. If used to encrypt a directory, it will apply encryption to ALL files in the directory which can break any JS, CSS, images, or other non-ColdFusion files.

They do also include this note at the bottom:

> Note: Encrypting your site files with cfencode does not guarantee absolute security of your source code, but it does add a layer of obfuscation to help prevent unauthorized individuals from viewing the source.

The article goes on to give basic instructions on how to use each.

Adobe has this note on [their site regarding cfencode](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/developing-cfml-applications/securing-applications/coldfusion-security-features.html):

> Note: You can also use the cfencode utility, located in the cf_root/bin directory, to obscure ColdFusion pages that you distribute. Although this technique cannot prevent persistent hackers from determining the contents of your pages, it does prevent inspection of the pages. The cfencode utility is not available on OS X.

***I would also add that it will be trivial for anyone familiar with ColdFusion to decode anything encoded with this utility because they also provide the decoder.***

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, CFCompile.bat gives me the same results as CFCompile.exe - all of the SQL queries in the files that it outputs are still readable. CFEncode seems to have worked a bit better (all of the SQL is obfuscated), but the pages don't display properly when I use the encoded version of the files.

Comment: Did you be sure to only CFEncode the .cfm and .cfc files?  As mentioned in that article.

Comment: I thought that I had only encoded the .cfm/.cfc files, but I must have somehow done the Javascripts folder too. I just copied the .cfm files out to another directory and encoded them there, and now everything is working. Thanks for the help

Comment: "...would be trivial for anyone familiar with ColdFusion to decode"  Yep. Can't emphasize that enough.

Comment: Agreed!. I updated the answer to highlight that text.